# How to use PreferenceScreen of Androidx

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences, androidx

My problem is that I wanted to *add a PreferenceScreen to my Application*, but I can't use it and I don't know why.

I implemented the library `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01`. Then I wanted to add the PreferenceScreen to my XML-layout and it doesn't suggest any suggestion.

Next, I copied the XML-Code from Android-Developers into my XML-layout and compiled it, but by starting the activity it breaks with the error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen cannot be cast to android.view.View`

Can somebody help me to use the `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` correctly?

My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <androidx.preference.SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="example_switch"
        android:summary="Turn this option on or off"
        android:title="Settings option" />
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout?

Comment: Yes, I can post my layout. There is it.

Comment: Also, your Preference activity would be helpful.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Now the whole answer:

> 1. Add this line to your App-Gradle: `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'` or `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'` for Kotlin. And sync Gradle. Create
>    a Directory named `xml` in res Folder.
> 2. Create in this directory an XML-File with your prefered name for example `main_preferences`. Root Element must be
>    `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen`.
> 3. Fill XML-File with your settings for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <androidx.preference.SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="example_switch"
        android:summary="Turn this option on or off"
        android:title="Settings option" />
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

> 4. Create somewhere in the folder com.???.??? a java file for example named `MainSettingsFragment`. Superclass (means `<Classname> extends <Superclass>`) must be `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and override
>    `onCreatePreferences`. You can copy this code:

```
import android.os.Bundle; 
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import com.???.???.R;

public class <YourClassname> extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.<yourXmlFilename>, rootKey);
    }
}
```

> 5. Next, there are two options to implement the PreferencesSreen in your .

The beautiful and best way is, it to implement it per code on creation.
Add in your `SettingsActivty` a `FrameLayout` and give it an ID for example `fl_main_settings`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/<!-- yourID -->">

</FrameLayout>
```

And in your Activity Code add really on the top of the onCreate method this:

```
package com.???.???;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.text.HtmlCompat;

import com.???.???.MainSettingsFragment;
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.<SettingsActivityXML(with the FrameLayout)>);

        //If you want to insert data in your settings
        <YourSettingsFragmentClass> settingsFragment = new <YourSettingsFragmentClass>();
        settingsFragment. ...
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.<YourFrameLayout>,settingsFragment).commit();
        
        //Else
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.<YourFrameLayout>,new <YourSettingsFragmentClass>()).commit();
    }
```

**Or** you implement a `Fragment` in your SettingsActivityXml. **But I don't recommend this ,because starting the activity takes a few seconds**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <fragment
        android:tag="frag"
        android:name="com.quickme.musicme.Fragments.MainSettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

That's it have fun.

Comment: Thank you for this tutorial, it's very clear. But can you make it clearer when you say (point 5) "Add in your a FrameLayout" you missed a word, no ? is it Add in your main_activity.xml a FrameLayout ??? or is it in another xml file ?

Comment: I keep getting "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setAdapter(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter)' on a null object reference" and only when I uncomment the line: "setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);" and the xml looks fine

Comment: Thank you, Christian. Unintentionally I commented it. Now I have fixed it

Comment: Where and why do you use a RecyclerView, Pete? I don't think that it's because of my code. Maybe you check your RecyclerView Adapter and its initialization ;)

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class `androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen` cannot be cast to `android.view.View`
>   My Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
...
</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

Pay attention.
It is **not** a layout.

> Can somebody help me to use the androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen correctly?

You can find all [info here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings).

You can define a Preference hierarchy.

> **Caution:** The root tag **must be** a `<PreferenceScreen>`, and the XML resource **must be placed** in the `res/xml/ directory`.

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    ....

</PreferenceScreen>
```

To inflate a hierarchy from an XML attribute, create a [`PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat), override [`onCreatePreferences()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#oncreatepreferences), and provide the XML resource:

```
class MySettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

then add this `Fragment` to your `Activity` as you would with any other `Fragment.

Answer (score -2):

Try: xml/preferences.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="example_switch"
        android:summary="Turn this option on or off"
        android:title="Settings option" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I also prefer using a preference fragment, hosted by my activity.

```
class MySettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings_container, SettingsFragment())
                .commit()
    }
}
```

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    }
}
```

Comment: The question asked for a solution in Java, and not kotlin