# Null point in sharedperfernces of subclass

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, androidx

I'm trying to update an older class to the androidx libraries. Previously it was written as

```java
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
...
public class LatinIMESettings extends PreferenceActivity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener,
        DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        ...
        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

There doesn't seem to be a direct analog to `PerferenceActivity` in androidx so I tried to rewrite it as

```java
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
...
public class LatinIMESettings extends FragmentActivity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener,
        DialogInterface.OnDismissListener {

    static class LatinIMESettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable String rootKey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs, rootKey);
        }
    }
    LatinIMESettingsFragment fragment = new LatinIMESettingsFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        fragment = new LatinIMESettingsFragment();
        ...
        SharedPreferences prefs = fragment.getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences();
        prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Right now I'm getting an NullPointerException when trying to get the sharedPerfernces

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5991458/23619351) says I need to call after I'm done with onCreate, but I'm not exactly sure when that should be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use PreferenceScreen of Androidx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466675/how-to-use-preferencescreen-of-androidx)

Comment: No. I'm still calling ``getSharedPreferences`` before ``onCreate`` is done., so that changes little. I also need the fragment for other initializing other preferences, so even if I ommit the line, other areas also throw a NullPointerException. The only way around it that I've had was moving stuff to an init function that I call in onResume or wherever I need preferences. But, that seems a bit of a clunky way to do it, so an answer that's more.. "correct" seems ideal